# How can I tell when the Parisian Zone buildings are finished upgrading?

Tags: simcity-buildit

I've noticed that the Parisian Zone buildings aren't high rises like the Residential Zone or Tokyo Town Zone buildings. Because I can't use their elevation to indicate when they're finished being upgraded, how can I tell if they're done or not?

(To be more clear, I know that buildings that are ready for upgrade have the construction hat bubble above them, but not all buildings that *can* be upgraded are ready to be upgraded.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the 12 Parisian buildings I have, all seem to be one of the three models when fully upgraded:

[image: Parisian residence 1] [image: Parisian residence 2] [image: Parisian residence 3]

Answer (score 0):

The max population for Paris buildings is around 2000. That number changes a little depending on if your building is next to a park, school or whatever. But generally around 2000 population. So hold ur finger on the building until you enter the residential edit mode and it will display how many people are in it.

Comment: This is not a terribly helpful answer, as I have a lot of population multipliers.

Comment: if you move it somewhere out of range of all these multipliers, then you can see the base amount of population of a building